# How to distinguish type object and array in TypeScript overload?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, types, overloading

This is my code:

```
public foo<T>(src: object, type: Type<T>): T;
public foo<T>(src: any[], type: Type<T>[]): T[];
public foo<T>(src: object | any[], type: Type<T> | Type<T>[]): T | T[] {...}
```

What I want to do is an overload that guarantees the following constraint:

- an object (not array), a Type > a single object
- an array, an array of Type > an array

The problem is that the type object can also be an array and therefore the following combination becomes possible:

```
foo([...], MyType) > {}
```

Is there a way to avoid it? Or can you recommend me a way to rewrite the overload?

Comment: What is that overload supposed to do? Are you sure that you want use `object` and `any[]` there?

Comment: I want to convert a plain object to a "class object" or an array of anything (including primitive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that an array is an object, so if the overload that takes an array parameter fails to match, Typescript will just move on to the next overload that takes an object and conclude that the first argument is compatible with the `object`.

We can use conditional types to introduce an incompatibility in the second argument if the first argument is an array on the object overload. Also if you need to infer more then one type for the array you will need to specify more type parameters, (one for each type up to a reasonable amount of types)

```
type Type<T> = new (...args:any[]) => T
type Type<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T
class C {
    public foo<T, P extends object>(src: P, type: P extends any[] ? never : Type<T>): T;
    public foo<T>(src: [any], type: [Type<T>]): [T];
    public foo<T, T1>(src: [any, any], type: [Type<T>, Type<T1>]): [T, T1];
    public foo<T, T1, T2>(src: [any, any, any], type: [Type<T>, Type<T1>, Type<T2>]): [T, T1, T2];
    public foo<T = any>(src: T[], type: Type<T>[]): T[]; // catch all oveload for arrays
    public foo(src: object | any[], type: Type<any> | Type<any>[]): any {

    }

}

class MyClass { private x!: string }
class MyClass2 { private x!: string }

let c = new C;
c.foo({}, MyClass) // ok, return My Class
c.foo({}, [MyClass]) // error
c.foo([], MyClass) // error
c.foo([{}], [MyClass]) // ok returns [MyClass]
c.foo([{}, {}], [MyClass, MyClass2]) // ok returns [MyClass, MyClass2]
c.foo([{}, {}, {}], [MyClass, MyClass2, MyClass]) // ok returns [MyClass, MyClass2, MyClass]
```

Comment: The problem here is that you always return T[], instead i need to return T if object and T[] if array. Maybe i can use conditional types on return type.. it does not become very readable, but it should work.

Comment: @nacho111 Just noticed using conditionals does not return infer `T` correctly for arrays. Then again even the original has problmes inferring multiple types types. Do you want the types array to contain multiple types ? If so we will need extra type parameters (one for each type up to an arbitrary amount )

Comment: No, i just need 1 type if array.

Comment: @nacho111 Then why pass an array ?

Comment: Ok sorry, my fault. YES, i need multiple types.

Comment: @nacho111 Updated the answer, sorry for the delay baby feeding time :)